# Why cannot load java.sql.Driver with URLClassloader(name, null) in Java 11

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

In Java 8, we can load MySQL Driver like this:

```
URLClassLoader mysql5ClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File(mysql5path).toURI().toURL()}, null);
Class<?> mysql5Class = mysql5ClassLoader.loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Driver mysql5Driver = (Driver) mysql5Class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

But in Java 11 (in fact, 9 or later), we must using

```
URLClassLoader mysql5ClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File(mysql5path).toURI().toURL()}, ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader());
```

I check the oracle doc found https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-A868D0B9-026F-4D46-B979-901834343F9E

> The changes that were implemented in JDK 9 may impact code that creates class loaders with null (that is, the bootstrap class loader) as the parent class loader and assumes that all platform classes are visible to the parent. Such code may need to be changed to use the platform class loader as the parent (see ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader).

Then I debug with `null` parent and `ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader()` parent found both above using ClassLoader.findClass(name), one get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver`, one can load MySQL Driver successfully.

Why and How get the different result

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. *"Why cannot load java.sql.Driver with URLClassloader(name, null) in Java 11"* - That is explained in the doc that you found.  In the text that you quoted.  *"Then I debug found both above using URLClassLoader.findClass()."* - Found both what?  What were you debugging?  *"Why and How get the different result?"* - No idea what you are asking here.

Comment: If you are asking why this changed, the answer is to support Java 9 modules, etc.  If you are asking if you can **avoid** changing your Java 8 classloading code to get it to work in Java 9+, the answer is (AFAIK) No.

Comment: @StephenC I just update my question, thanks :)

Comment: OK.  So the answer to the *revised* question is in the text that you quoted.  So, I'm still unclear what you are actually asking here.  (You clearly know how to make the code work on Java 11.  What else is there that is relevant to solving your problem?)

Comment: @StephenC I know how to solve the problem, but also want to know why doing so can work? After debugging I found before invoke native method defineClass1() no differences between null parent or platformClassLoader parent. After defineClass1(), it throws Error.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `null` as the parent classloader, you are telling this classloader to resolve platform classes in the bootstrap classloader.

That (typically) worked prior to Java 9 because all Java platform classes were loaded via the bootstrap classloader.

It (typically) doesn't work from Java 9 onwards, because in Java 9 they introduced modules and changed what classloaders loaded what platform classes.  Most platform classes are now loaded by a different classloader.  (Specifically by the classloader returned by `getPlatformClassLoader()`.)

So ... in Java 9 ... if you create a classloader with a `null` parent, then class loading a JDBC driver is liable to fail ... because the bootstrap classloader doesn't know about the platform classes that the driver depends on.

Note: this is simply an elaboration of what the text you quoted in your question actually says.

---

Q: Why did they change it?

A: Because it was necessary to support modules and to fix the problem of the SE libraries being monolithic.

Q: Can you avoid fixing your code?

A: Not if you want to create the classloader dynamically like that.  But you wouldn't have this problem if you simply included the driver in the launch-time classpath; e.g. using `-cp ...`.

Comment: In Java 9, both `null` or `getPlatformClassLoader`.
```
                    if (parent != null) {
                        c = parent.loadClass(name, false);
                    } else {
                        c = findBootstrapClassOrNull(name);
                    }
```
will fail to load class, then ClassLoader: 588 `c = findClass(name);` works.
In getPlatformClassLoader case, the parent ClassLoader (platformclassloader) seems can NOT load the class, but findClass(name) loads the Class

Comment: I'm not English spoken, sry

Comment: Sorry.  It is too hard to figure out what you are saying.

Comment: If using `null` as parent, it will invoke defineClass1(args...). and using `getPlatformClassLoader` as parent, it invoke defineClass1(args...), too. But they have different result. 

I have no idea about what the native method `defineClass1(args..)` actually do.

Comment: Well yes.  But what happens >inside< `defineClass1` if the JVM needs to resolve a reference to another class?  Answer: it uses `this` to try to find the other class, and that delegates to the parent classloader.  (This is standard classloader behavior.)

Comment: That was what I am wondering about. I thought it delegate to its parent classloader at `ClassLoader.loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)` where call `loadClass(name, false)` using parent (line 575 at Classloader.java)...But there is an another delegate happened inside `definedClass1`, is that right?

Comment: That is correct.  It happens when the class you are loading has references to other classes.  (And that will be almost all of the time ...)

Comment: You also wouldn’t have the problem if you never specified the superfluous `, null` at the `URLClassLoader` construction.

Comment: Because I want to load class with different classloader

Comment: @YangZhou when you start a sentence with “because”, there should be a preceding “why” question. There is no such question in the comments, so it’s not clear what you are responding to.